# Proper name for banknote values (sizes)?

Tags: terminology, cash, paper-money

For example USD uses $1, *$2*, $5, $10, $20, $50, $100.

What is a proper name for these options?

If I want to give someone $1000, what would be the proper way of asking them what is the largest bill size they would accept?

Comment: [meta question:] Should this be on ELL.SE?

Comment: This is absolutely an ELL question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly related to personal finance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like you are talking about the [denomination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denomination_(currency)) of the banknote.

Comment: So the question "What is the highest denomination you accept?" is correct?

Comment: @TadijaBagarić: Yes, or "largest denomination".

Comment: It's colloquial to say "largest bill".

Comment: I would add that each bill is commonly called by its denomination. So a $20 bill would simply be called a "twenty", a $5 bill would be called a "five", etc. Someone might say, "Can I get change for this twenty? I need three fives and five ones."- meaning that they will give you a $20 bill in return for three $5 bills and five $1 bills.